# Converting from UTF8 to ISO 8859-5, getting ISO 8859-1 instead

Tags: file, encoding, utf-8, iso

I need to convert a file to 8-bit(Cyrillic/8859-5), so I'm doing

```
iconv --from-code=UTF-8 --to-code=ISO-8859-5 file.UTF8 -o file.ISO
```

It works and finally when I check the encoding I get

```
file -bi file.ISO
text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1
```

Why ISO-8859-1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command [`file`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_%28command%29) only makes guesses at a files encoding. It probably would be hard to determine [ISO 8859-5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-5) over [ISO 8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) without looking the words up in a dictionary database because they are both similar 8 bit formats.

As long as you know the file is really ISO 8859-5, that's what matters.

**Note:** I have just learnt that (confusingly) [ISO 8859-9](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-9) is aparently informally referred to as "*Latin-5*", so I have removed references to that confusing name.